# how to create a parameter in spagoBi studio with multiple values

Tags: spagobi, fiware-knowage

how to create a parameter in spagoBI studio with multiple values. i am creating a report and want the queries to be run for multiple selection values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That parameter should be a string text box. because SpagoBI gives multiple selected values as a string.If the report is a birt report, check this out. [How to implement in SpagoBI Server a BIRT report parameter that allows multiple values](http://www.spagoworld.org/jforum/posts/list/1559.page). read the first reply.

Good Luck..!!!

Comment: i have read the post .. I am able to make the report in studio but when i upload it in server it is giving blank report. do you know the solution. The logs giving the error:  The type of parameter "..." is expected as "Object[]", not "java.lang.String"

Comment: your multiple selection parameter should be **string text box**. it cannot be check box. just create a string text box. after you upload it to the server, use LOV to give values. which report did you use? birt or jasper?